# Support for multiple authentication and authorization methos in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am working on an asp.net web api project that can be used by developers who wants to use my company's resources. So i want to support multiple authentication-authorization types like (oauth1, oauth2 or basichttp...) So how can i achive to understand which method is user using to grant access to my api methods? I know this is a comprehensive question but any resources and examples would be appreciated(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: You should be the one who decides what authorization mechanism to use. It's your API so you should set standards for your API. If you try to satisfy all the clients requirements then your API will be always in maintenance mode.

Comment: You just has to start parsing the data the user is sending, and check against the standards for the methods you are supporting. Or, better, have a look at Azure AD, Auth0 or other services that take the burden of different authentication services, and give you one protocol to handle.

Comment: You can offer different authentication mechanisms such as username and password or active directory etc. This will be a very complex solution. But once the user is authenticated successfully, whether to issue OAuth2 token of OAuth1 token or JWT token that should be decided by you.